# Completely replace glBindTexture using DSA

Tags: c++, opengl

Using the [Direct Access Extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt) I can replace many calls, which require glBindTexture, with their bindless counterparts, [example](http://www.geeks3d.com/20101228/opengl-direct-state-access-dsa/):

```
//Without DSA:
glGenTextures(1, &tid);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixmap);

//With DSA:
glGenTextures(1, &tid);
glTextureImage2DEXT(tid, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixmap);
```

I am wondering - is it possible to completely get rid of glBindTexture calls? Is there a way to replace this code for example, where we connect the active texture to the uniform sampler:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(texture, 0);
```

My personal impression is that it is not possible but I wish to hear if there is someone who thinks differently.

Comment: So you want [ARB_bindless_texture](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/bindless_texture.txt)?

Comment: This might very well be. Thank you, I will look at it properly.

Comment: You have the wrong idea about the DSA extension. It is to eliminate the selector/latch mechanism for *changing states*, in other words, it eliminates bind-then-modify. The purpose of binding a texture in this case is so the sampler has a source of data, not to change the texture's state, so DSA does not apply here. However, part of DSA will allow you to bind that texture to an explicit Texture Image Unit, without first calling `glActiveTexture (...)`, this function is called `glBindMultiTextureEXT (...)`.

Comment: Note: `glBindMultiTextureEXT` is now `glBindTextures` in `ARB_multi_bind` core in 4.4.